# Crash when I attempt to call context in a fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-context

The logcat says:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method '...' on a null object 
>    reference

I call context when I add a child to "root_view". It seems that 
 `getActivity()` doesn't work properly. I searched everywhere but I didn't find any solution. Maybe the problem is `onAttach` method? Or maybe I have to create a class between `MainActivity` and fragment?

Here is my fragment's code:

```
 public class Profilo extends Fragment {

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public Profilo() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

       public static Profilo newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Profilo fragment = new Profilo();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

        ArrayList<String> namesOfNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();

        namesOfNumbers.add("uno");
        namesOfNumbers.add("due");
        namesOfNumbers.add("tre");
        namesOfNumbers.add("quattro");
        namesOfNumbers.add("cinque");
        namesOfNumbers.add("sei");
        namesOfNumbers.add("sette");
        namesOfNumbers.add("otto");
        namesOfNumbers.add("nove");
        namesOfNumbers.add("dieci");


        LinearLayout root_view = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_main_profilo);
        TextView word_view_1 = new TextView(getActivity());
        word_view_1.setText(namesOfNumbers.get(0));
        root_view.addView(word_view_1);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profilo, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context,"NOTIFICATION FRAGMENT ATTACHED",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

}
```

Comment: getactivity() will work fine, make sure that you have used supported fragment manager instead of fragment manager in the activity

Comment: you can pass your context to constructor from calling activity or you can call getApplicationContext()

Comment: Yes i used supportFragmentManager, and I have tried getApplicationContext() too.

Comment: Add your views inside onCreateView method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- At first **`RETURN`** view;
- Call **`LinearLayout`**,**`TextView`**  within **`onCreateView`**.

Try with

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profilo, null);
        LinearLayout root_view = (LinearLayout) view .findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_main_profilo);
        TextView word_view_1 = new TextView(getActivity());
        word_view_1.setText(namesOfNumbers.get(0));
        root_view.addView(word_view_1);

        return view;
}
```

Comment: There you go :) Guy is so quick!